# From warm to cold

Tags: riddle, word

I'm the start, my brother's the end.
We're the places, where you'll be or have been.
We sound similar but yet aren't the same.
I bet that you know our names.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Are these places

> womb & tomb?

Comment: Your answer is short and precise. That are the words I am looking for

Answer (score 14):

I know this is answered already, but another pair that might work is

> **Here** and **there**

I'm the start, my brother's the end.

> To go anywhere, you have to start from "here" (where you are) to get "there" (where you want to go).

We're the places, where you'll be or have been.

> "There" is a place you can be, and of course you've been "here"—you're there now!

We sound similar but yet aren't the same.

> Spelled very similarly, and pronounced somewhat alike, but describe places that can never be the same.

I bet that you know our names.

> Yep.

Comment: Nice take on the riddle!

Comment: @Phylyp Thanks! The problem with coming across these from HNQ is that they're almost always answered already... No problem though, this community seems to appreciate a clever answer even if it's not the intended solution!

Comment: This answer is excellent but I think it doesn't fit the title.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Well, maybe not without some twisting and stretching ;) Fair point though—forgot that the title was a clue also

Comment: I like your answer. Maybe I will create another riddle using your answer :)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel It's a stretch, but rot13(obql jnezgu)?

Comment: @LarsW that was the best I could come up with also

Answer (score 1):

It's

> a *bowl*

I'm the start, my brother's the end.

> We eat our food from a bowl. Then it ends in a different bowl - the toilet one (passing through yet another kind of bowels, but I digress)

We're the places, where you'll be or have been.

> Sure, everyone eats.

We sound similar but yet aren't the same.

> I'll bet!